# issue with sudoku game in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sudoku

so here is my code so far, thanks to an earlier question on here I managed to change to code around and I can get it to run to about number 4 before it gives an error. A couple things to point out is that it check each row and column and if they are clear of the current number than it puts a true in a list. It then uses those trues and false like a grid, so if the rows were (true,true,false) and the columns were (false,true,true) then the acceptable places within the block would be ([0,1],[0,2],[1,1],[1,2]), this helps keep random guessing to a minimal. The problem I am encountering is that it is running out of location that are available by the fourth number. Help is very welcome

```
#sudoku game
import random
#generate board
def build_board():
    board=[]
    for i in range(81):
        board.append(str(i)) #add numbers not empty spaces to help in index identification
    return board
#add numbers
def fill_board(board):
    change_board=board[:] #board to add changes to
    current_num=1 #current number to place
    for number in range(9): #for the 9 numbers
        current_block=0 #block currently on
        for time in range(9):
            #get block
            block=[] #block list
            for i in board:
                Inti=int(i)
                pos=Inti // 27 * 3 + Inti % 9 // 3
                if pos==current_block:
                    if isinstance(i,int)==True:
                        block.append(int(i))
                    elif isinstance(i,str)==True:
                        block.append(str(i))
            #check row
            TF_rows=[]
            if current_block in (0,1,2): #which rows to check for this block
                row_list=[0,1,2]
            elif current_block in (3,4,5):
                row_list=[3,4,5]
            elif current_block in (6,7,8):
                row_list=[6,7,8]
            for i in row_list: #for each of those rows
                #get index's from board to then get list of current numbers from change_board
                row_index=[]
                for num in board: #test all numbers in board to see if in this row
                    num=int(num)
                    pos=num//9
                    if pos==i: #if it is in row
                        row_index.append(num)
                current_row=[]
                for index in row_index: #use index's to check against the change board
                    to_add=change_board[index] #for each index
                    if isinstance(to_add,int)==True:
                        current_row.append(int(to_add))
                    elif isinstance(to_add,str)==True:
                        current_row.append(str(to_add))
                if current_num in current_row:
                    TF_rows.append("false")
                elif current_num not in current_row:
                    TF_rows.append("true")
            #check columns
            TF_columns=[]
            if current_block in (0,3,6):
                column_list=[0,1,2]
            elif current_block in (1,4,7):
                column_list=[3,4,5]
            elif current_block in (2,5,8):
                column_list=[6,7,8]
            for i in column_list:
                #get index's from board to then use to get list of current numbers from board changed
                column_index=[]
                for num in board:
                    num=int(num)
                    pos=num%9
                    if pos==i:
                        column_index.append(num)
                current_column=[]
                for index in column_index:
                    to_add=change_board[index]
                    if isinstance(to_add,int)==True:
                        current_column.append(int(to_add))
                    elif isinstance(to_add,str)==True:
                        current_column.append(str(to_add))
                if current_num in current_column:
                    TF_columns.append("false")
                elif current_num not in current_column:
                    TF_columns.append("true")
            #evaluate true/false statements to get (x,y) type lists
            positions=[]
            ROW=0
            for i in TF_rows:
                COLUMN=0
                for subI in TF_columns:
                    if i=="true" and subI=="true":
                        add_pos=[ROW,COLUMN]
                        #check to make sure position is clear, get index's from block and then use on change_board
                        if ROW==0:
                            ROW_INDEX=0
                        elif ROW==1:
                            ROW_INDEX=3
                        elif ROW==2:
                            ROW_INDEX=6
                        pos_to_check=ROW_INDEX + COLUMN
                        check_index=int(block[pos_to_check])
                        check=change_board[check_index]
                        if isinstance(check,str)==True:
                            positions.append(add_pos)
                    COLUMN+=1
                ROW+=1
            #change number
            try:
                add_position=random.choice(positions) #edit###if you add this try and              except in then you can see that it gets pretty close to having the final answer, but not     quite
            except:
                pass
            ROW=add_position[0]
            COLUMN=add_position[1]
            if ROW==0:
                ROW_INDEX=0
            elif ROW==1:
                ROW_INDEX=3
            elif ROW==2:
                ROW_INDEX=6
            add_pos=ROW_INDEX+COLUMN
            block_index=int(block[add_pos])
            change_board[block_index]=current_num
            current_block+=1
        current_num+=1
    return change_board

#display board
def display(board):
    slicers=[0,9] #slice points
    row_counter=0 #counts row to know when to place double line
    for i in range(9): #for all the rows
        RP=board[slicers[0]:slicers[1]] #sliced board
        if row_counter in (3,6):
            print("---------------------------------------")
            print("---------------------------------------")
        else:
            print("---------------------------------------")
        print("| {} | {} | {} || {} | {} | {} || {} | {} | {} |".format(RP[0],RP[1],RP[2],RP[3],RP[4],RP[5],RP[6],RP[7],RP[8]))
        row_counter+=1 #update counter
        slicers[0]+=9 #update slicers
        slicers[1]+=9 #update slicers
    print("---------------------------------------")        

#test
board=build_board()
fill=fill_board(board)
display=display(fill)
```

another thing is the reason that there are two boards has to do with using the one to check indexs with for testing for rows, columns, and blocks. While the other holds the number that have been changed

Thanks,
Jacob

Comment: Does this belong on Code Review?

Comment: @SimonT I don't does it? I haven't been using this website to long so I don't know were it goes.